# C# word like FormatPainter

Tags: c#, fonts, richtextbox

In Microsoft Office Word there's this function called Format Painter, this copies all properties of a text (Color, FontFamily & FontSize) and stores it whilst it waits for the next selection to be made, this is a function I need to make in an assignment for school as well, but I have no idea how to do this, I've tried to store the properties in variables and using them in a SelectionChanged function to paste them over the selected text, but this did not work as I need it to work, I need it to work exactly like the one in Word, but this will be in a richtextbox in C#

Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried to do it like this:

```
private bool copiedSelection = false;

        void FormatPainter()
        {
            var fc = new FontConverter();
            Font f1 = new Font(rtxtInhoud.SelectionFont.FontFamily, rtxtInhoud.SelectionFont.Size);
            Color c1 = rtxtInhoud.SelectionColor;
            var fontAsString = fc.ConvertToInvariantString(f1); 
            Font f2 = (Font)fc.ConvertFromInvariantString(fontAsString);
            font = f2.ToString();
            kleur = c1.ToString();
            var color = Regex.Match(kleur, @"\[(.*?)\]").Groups[1];
            kleur = color.ToString();
            copiedSelection = true;
         }

private void rtxtInhoud_SelectionChanged(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (copiedSelection == true && ))
        {
            rtxtInhoud.SelectionColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(kleur);
        }
        copiedSelection = false;
    }
```

Comment: Keep coding, you're on the right track. Two notes: 1) There is no need to cast color to string or back! 2) The `SelectionChanged` event will fire not only when a selection is made, but also when it is removed. So you should start with maybe a check like this: `if (!copiedSelection || RTB.SelectionLength <= 0) return;`

Comment: So basicly, make sure the SelectionChanged does NOT fire when the selection is removed @TaW

Comment: Indeed or else you clear the copiedSelection without having anything to style..

Comment: Do you have some tips on how to do this, also how I'd pass on the font family & font size, I'm kind of stuck on this @TaW

Comment: You need to store the format data in a persistent spot; the simplest would be to move the variables out of the FormatPainter function to class level..

Comment: Alright, but how can I get the font family & the size seperatly? @TaW

Comment: Fonts are a little special, eg in that they are 'immutable' . Here is how to set the Size:  `RTB.SelectionFont = new Font (sFont.FontFamily, sFontSize); - RTB is my richtextbox and float sFontSize is where I have stored the size and sFont is the stored Font..
`

Comment: yeah that's how you set it, but what I'm stuck on is retrieving and storing the size seperatly @TaW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short example, using two Buttons: one to store some format data and one to paint the current selection with the stored format data.

The `SelectionChanged` event calls the second button and then clears the flag that indicates that format data are currently loaded.

```
    bool loaded = false;

    Font sFont;
    Color sColor;
    Color sBackcolor;
    float sFontSize;
    HorizontalAlignment sAlign;
    //..

    private void cb_store_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loaded = true;
        sFont = RTB.SelectionFont;
        sColor =   RTB.SelectionColor;
        sAlign = RTB.SelectionAlignment;
        sBackcolor = RTB.BackColor;
        sFontSize = RTB.SelectionFont.Size;
        //..
    }

    private void cb_paint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RTB.SelectionFont = sFont;
        RTB.SelectionColor = sColor ;
        RTB.SelectionAlignment = sAlign;
        RTB.BackColor = sBackcolor;
        RTB.SelectionFont = new Font(sFont.FontFamily, sFontSize);
        //..
    }

    private void RTB_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!loaded || RTB.SelectionLength <= 0) return;
        cb_paint_Click(null, null);
        loaded = false;
    }
```

Note that `RTB` is the `RichTextBox`; only a few format data are covered; there are many more:   `SelectionBullet, SelectionCharOffset, SelectionHangingIndent,  RTB.SelectionIndent, RTB.SelectionRightIndent`

Also note that you will need to clear the flag on several other occasions!

You can replace the `cb_paint_Click` by a function, of course..

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this has really helped me out, what I've done now is I've taken the contents of your cb_store_Click and cb_paint_Click and placed them in my functions accordingly, the store in the FormatPainter() function and the paint in the SelectionChanged function

Comment: Good. Now to the next task: Word lets you keep the format set if you click the format painter button with, I believe Ctrl-Key pressed. hint: I would use a second flag ;-)